# Build is not working in react using vite bundler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, tailwind-3

[image]

I use web-pack before and wanted to change it to vite I copied all the file from the web-pack version to the vite version
when I issue `yarn dev` it work but we I build it and run the build with `serve dist` it give me this error on the browser and it won't render any thing

Comment: Have you tried `npm isntall` again so all dependencies can be installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was with a react library called react-custom-scrollbars

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue with react-custom-scrollbars-2. It's quite strange that Vite doesn't show just errors in dev mode.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this config, (take a look at `@vitejs/plugin-react` which you probably need to install)

`vite.config.js`:

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      react(),
    ],
  });
};
```

The thing is that vite does not import React by default into jsx components, so you need to do it manually in every component or use this plugin.

Comment: this now comes with new vite react installation by default.